# React navigation giving undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make a back button in react native and using navigation.goBack() in the function component but if I console the navigation then it's giving me undefined

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import backIcon from '../assets/back-black.png';
const {width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: SCREEN_HEIGHT} = Dimensions.get('window');

const TitleHeader = ({navigation, title}) => {
  // console.log("hello");
  return (
    <View style={[styles.customHeader]}>
      <View style={[styles.headerLeft]}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <Image source={backIcon} style={styles.headerIcon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={[styles.font, styles.headerTitle]}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

The rest of the code is working fine I am just getting an error in navigation so I add the important code only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-navigation v5 provides hook useNavigation() returns the navigation prop of the screen it's inside.
Sample:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyBackButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

In your code you need pass prop navigation to your component

Comment: What if i have react navigation 4

Comment: In src/screens/ then all the screens are in this folder

Comment: So you need pass navigation prop like < TitleHeader navigation={navigation}/>. navigation is props of the screen when you navigate